# Drupal Translate Taxonomy Terms in views

Tags: localization, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

**Please Help**

Here is my steps and my problem :

1. Installed Locale,Taxonomy, Taxonomy translation, Views translation modules
2. Added vocabulary
3. Chose this option **Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.**
4. Created Terms for this vocabulary and translate them
5. Created view to display the taxonomies

This works fine if you accessed the term link and changed the language **en/taxonomy/term/5** to **gr/taxonomy/term/5**, but not working when I get the data through views, I searched the whole web for a solution but I couldn't find one!

Answer (score 0):

I found fix for my problem, i hope i can help any one how facing the same problem, using i18n_taxonomy_localize_terms function

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79037/get-translated-term-name/81047#81047

Comment: Drupal have this bug in views, after lots of searching i found that this fix solved my issue, if you have another fix please share it